# Are User Parameters accesible by pre or post processors?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

[image: Test]

in User parameters I have:

[image: User Parameters]

in User Defined Variables I have:

[image: User Defined Variables]

In pre processor I have:

```
def varB = vars.get("varB");
def varA = vars.get("varA");
log.info(varB);
log.info(varA);
```

in post processor I have:

```
def varA = vars.get("varA");
def varB = vars.get("varB");
log.info("varA = $varA");
log.info("varB = $varB");
vars.put("varB", "varA");
log.info("After change = $varB");
```

But varB is not updating:

```
2023-03-04 12:51:33,674 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: xyz
2023-03-04 12:51:33,674 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: abc
2023-03-04 12:51:33,913 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: varA = abc
2023-03-04 12:51:33,914 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: varB = xyz
2023-03-04 12:51:33,914 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: After change = xyz
```

I am trying to store the value of `varA` so that I can use it in another test payload (same thread group, and I do not want to use properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's accessible in  your case.
the mistake is in saving the parameter. instead of passing the variable, you passed that as string

```
def varA = vars.get("varA");
def varB = vars.get("varB");
log.info("varA = $varA");
log.info("varB = $varB");
vars.put("varB", varA);
log.info("After change = "+ vars.get("varB"));
```

This gives the below expected output

*

```
2023-03-04 23:33:43,691 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-03-04 23:33:43,707 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: xyz
2023-03-04 23:33:43,707 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: abc
2023-03-04 23:33:43,753 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: varA = abc
2023-03-04 23:33:43,753 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: varB = xyz
2023-03-04 23:33:43,753 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: After change = abc
```

- 

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
vars.put("varB", "varA");
```

with this one:

```
vars.put("varB", vars.get("varA"));
```

as you're passing hard-coded string of `varA` instead of the variable value.

Also it might be easier to use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) or [Debug Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) in combination with the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener instead of printing the values to the jmeter.log file